# How to add nan to the end of an array using numpy

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have a list of multiple arrays and I want them to have the same size, filling the ones with less elements with nan. I have some arrays that have integers and others that have string.

For example:

```
a = ['Nike']
b = [1,5,10,15,20]
c = ['Adidas']
d = [150, 2]
```

I have tried

```
max_len = max(len(a),len(b),len(c),len(d))

empty = np.empty(max_len - len(a))
a = np.asarray(a) + empty

empty = np.empty(max_len - len(b))
b = np.asarray(b) + empty
```

I do the same with all of the arrays, however an error occurs (TypeError: only integer scalar arrays can be converted to a scalar index)

I am doing this because I want to make a DataFrame with all of the arrays being a different columns.

Thank you in advanced

Answer (score 3):

How about this?

`df1 = pd.DataFrame([a,b,c,d]).T`

Comment: suggest adding .values at the end to convert back to np.aray

`arr1 = pd.DataFrame([a,b,c,d]).T.values`

Answer (score 3):

I'd suggest using `lists` since you also have `strings`. Here's one way using `zip_longest`:

```
from itertools import zip_longest

a, b, c, d = map(list,(zip(*zip_longest(a,b,c,d, fillvalue=float('nan')))))
```

---

```
print(a)
# ['Nike', nan, nan, nan, nan]

print(b)
# [1, 5, 10, 15, 20]

print(c)
# ['Adidas', nan, nan, nan, nan]

print(d)
# [150, 2, nan, nan, nan]
```

---

Another approach could be:

```
max_len = len(max([a,b,c,d], key=len))
a, b, c, d = [l+[float('nan')]*(max_len-len(l)) for l in [a,b,c,d]]
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use the `numpy.append(array, value, axis)` to append to an array. In you example that would be `ans = np.append(a,empty)`.

Answer (score 0):

You can do that directly just like so:

```
>>> import pandas as pd

>>> a = ['Nike']
>>> b = [1,5,10,15,20]
>>> c = ['Adidas']
>>> d = [150, 2]

>>> pd.DataFrame([a, b, c, d])
        0    1     2     3     4
0    Nike  NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN
1       1  5.0  10.0  15.0  20.0
2  Adidas  NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN
3     150  2.0   NaN   NaN   NaN
```